# How to show that Loading Circle between activity transition?

Tags: android

I got two activities Activity1 and Activity2. When clicked on button, I am switching from Activity1 to Activity2. But Activity2 is taking a lot of time to load due to slow internet speed. Empty screen is shown till the activity is loaded.

Instead of the black screen, I want to show a progress bar and when the Activity2 is ready, then close progress bar without making the user to get frustrated.

I don't have any idea of how to do this or start this. I am new to android. Please help me by suggesting idea or please share any links regarding this!!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

In the on create of activity2 before you begin the internet procedure (or if you are doing it inside an async task, then in the preexecute method) you create a progress dialog
and when the task is finished (in asynctask in the post execute) you dismiss the dialog

Comment: Kindly comment when giving a DOWN to the answer.

Answer (score -3):

You must be using `startActivity(intent)` to start the 2nd activity. place that code in a thread and start the `AlertDialog` just before that. Stop the `AlertDialog` in the handler of the `Thread`

Place a `view` inside the `AlertDialog`. The view contains a `ProgressBar`(Circular)

Comment: Some seriously stupid person is giving downs. If you don't get android, don't ask here.

Comment: here is your comment: why are you correcting english and downvoting ? if you didn't like the way i wrote it, you could have said so, without downvoting

Comment: Look @LenaBru I haven't downvoted. Infact I am searching the one who is doing this. Because the same person downvoted my answer too.

Comment: ok np (and to make this comment long enough)

Comment: Infact i supported you by commenting and asking who downvoted for your answer. @LenaBru

Comment: Why the hell people down vote without telling the reasons